# Nginx location and reverse proxy configuration not working properly

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Currently, all requests under '/_webapi' are being forwarded to http://myproject.webapi/api with this configuration:

```
upstream web_api {
    server myproject.webapi:80;
}
server {
    location /_webapi {
        proxy_pass         http://web_api/api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to remove the '/api' part. After I made some configuration from the web-api and use this configuration, it seems like it doesn't work:

```
server {
    location /_webapi {
        proxy_pass         http://web_api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

If directly accessed `http://myproject.webapi/values` and `http://myproject.webapi/weatherforecast` works fine. But when through Nginx reverse proxy using URL like `http://localhost/_webapi/values` or `http://localhost/_webapi/weatherforecast`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Currently you are passing `/_webapi` to `http://web_api/_webapi`. You should add a trailing `/` to the `location` and `proxy_pass` statements.

Comment: what do you get from `sudo nginx -t` ?

Comment: Can you write the full configuration, your passing Host header to proxy, just curious if upstream server block match the same host name.

Comment: Check with this  proxy_set_header   Host "myproject.webapi";